# Как расставить знаки препинания? Четверостишье

Tags: запятые, тире, и

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как бы вы расставили знаки препинания в данном четверостишье:

> За Ваш неоценимый вклад в работу мы признательны,
> За труд, профессионализм, за ваш авторитет(! или ,)
> И что с коллективом были так доброжелательны,
> За справедливость Вашу(,) ну и за опыт (—) долгих лет.